# How to send and use serialized object from code behind to JS?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, javascriptserializer

I want to send serialized object from C# to JS.
The code is:

```
var RegisteredUsers = new List<Person>();
        RegisteredUsers.Add(new Person() { PersonID = 1, Name = "Bryon Hetrick", Registered = true });
        RegisteredUsers.Add(new Person() { PersonID = 2, Name = "Nicole Wilcox", Registered = true });
        RegisteredUsers.Add(new Person() { PersonID = 3, Name = "Adrian Martinson", Registered = false });
        RegisteredUsers.Add(new Person() { PersonID = 4, Name = "Nora Osborn", Registered = false });

        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var serializedResult = serializer.Serialize(RegisteredUsers);
```

now,

1)How can i sent it to client side?

2)How i can  access to every element (i.e i want to take the name who has ID

Thanks .

Comment: This is not enough info to answer. Are you using a framework? Have you tried to form a response containing the serialized data yet?

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET or are you just running a console app? How about MVC or WebAPI?

Comment: @styfle yes i'm using ASP.NET.
I did "http.get" in the client side to get the data . In the server side i prepared all the data like i mentioned above. now what should i do?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using MVC C# with Razor: put `serializedResult` in a ViewBag then use `@Html.Raw` to inject it in your JavaScript. I haven't tested this so let me know if it doesn't work.

C#:

```
var serializedResult = serializer.Serialize(RegisteredUsers);
ViewBag.RegisteredUsers = serializedResult;
```

JS:

```
var myUsers = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.RegisteredUsers));
```

---

EDIT: It seems you are actually using WebForms. They don't have ViewBag so you will have to set a property in your class.

C#:

```
protected string Users { get; set; }
```

C# (in Page_Load or wherever you are creating your List):

```
var serializedResult = serializer.Serialize(RegisteredUsers);
this.Users = serializedResult;
```

JS (WebForms syntax)

```
var myUsers = <%= Users %>
```

Comment: What is Razor? what should i import (i.e. using) I'm pretty new in WEB world and how can i access to specific data with "myUser" variable?

Comment: Razor allows you to do C# things in HTML. If you have .cshtml files you are using Razor.

Comment: You shouldn't need to import anything if you have .cshtml files. By "access" do you mean you want to display your data on the page?

Comment: i dont have cshtml files i have aspx.cs files

Comment: I forgot to mention I've edited my answer. Please upvote if you find my answer helpful!